# Can't find Android Size Analyzer in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

According to https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size, I should be able to install Android Size Analyzer as a plugin, but nothing shows up.

Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Plugin -> Marketplace -> search for "Android Size Analyzer"

[image]

Comment: "The Size Analyzer was an experimental project that is not actively supported by Google."  This comment was added Jan 29, 2021. So if you want the addon most likely you have to install it manually from the Github project release

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE: 17th May 2022

After a lot of trials, errors & frustration, **I was able to make it work**. Here are the steps: (for MacOS)

1. Download the the plugin's zip folder from the Github https://github.com/android/size-analyzer/releases
2. Extract the zip and add the `size-analyzer` executable and the `analyzer.jar` to `Users/<your_user>/Library/Android/platform-tools`

###### (You can add the above files to any place but I bundled it with platform-tools because this location was already present in my $PATH variable. Wherever you place those two files, please make sure that this location is present in your $PATH variable else it won't work. Don't know how to set path variables? Please refer this https://techpp.com/2021/09/08/set-path-variable-in-macos-guide)

3. Now in your Android Studio Terminal, run the following command

```
size-analyzer check-project <your-path-to-project-directory>
```

(After above step, If the terminal complains like `size-analyzer command not found`, it means your `$PATH` variable is not set properly)

After analyzing the entire project, it shows output like this

[image]

The result analysis provides lots of suggestions and space saving options. Thank you Google for such amazing plugin : )

=================

#### OLD : 16th May 2022

The **AS** plugin **Android Size Analyzer** is deprecated! It's no more indexed on Plugin Market Place(*You cannot install it directly from AS anymore)*.

I even tried installing the plugin from their GitHub Repo, but all in vain. When adding the plugin to studio from disk, the following error popped up.
Maybe you can try downgrading the studio and then install it.

[image]

Looks like, we'll be on our own for a while : (

Comment: which PATH we need to add for command not found?

Comment: Hoping the directory Library/Android lies on your root user folder, my .zshrc script looked like this,
`export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

After this, add the size analyzer jar to platform-tools directory, so that it becomes accessible from terminal. Run the command, it should work now.